# Getting "Transport endpoint is not connected" in UDP socket programming in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, udp

I am getting `Transport endpoint is not connected` error in UDP server program, while I am try to
shutdown the socket via `shutdown(m_ReceiveSocketId, SHUT_RDWR);`
Following is my code snippet:

```
 bool UDPSocket::receiveMessage()
    {
        struct sockaddr_in serverAddr; //Information about the server
        struct hostent *hostp; // Information about this device 

        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE]; // Buffer to store incoming message
        int serverlen; // to store server address length

        //Open a datagram Socket
        if((m_ReceiveSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            Utility_SingleTon::printLog(LOG_ERROR,"(%s %s %d) UDP Client - socket() error",__FILE__,__func__, __LINE__);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
            return false;
        }


        //Configure Server Address.
        //set family and port
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(m_ListeningPort);

        if (bind(m_ReceiveSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0 )
        {
            Utility_SingleTon::printLog(LOG_ERROR,"(%s %s %d) UDP Client- Socket Bind error=%s",__FILE__,__func__, __LINE__,strerror(errno));
            pthread_exit(NULL);
            return false;
        }

        //TODO Re-Route Mechanism.
        if((serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(m_ServerIPStr.c_str())) == (unsigned long)INADDR_NONE)
        {
            /* Use the gethostbyname() function to retrieve */
            /* the address of the host server if the system */
            /* passed the host name of the server as a parameter. */
            /************************************************/
            /* get server address */
            hostp = gethostbyname(m_ServerIPStr.c_str());
            if(hostp == (struct hostent *)NULL)
            {
                /* h_errno is usually defined */
                /* in netdb.h */
                Utility_SingleTon::printLog(LOG_ERROR,"%s %d %s %s %d", "Host Not found",  h_errno,__FILE__,__func__, __LINE__);
                pthread_exit(NULL);
                return false;
            }
            memcpy(&serverAddr.sin_addr, hostp->h_addr, sizeof(serverAddr.sin_addr));
        }


        serverlen = (int )sizeof(serverAddr);

        // Loop and listen for incoming message 
        while(m_RecevieFlag)
        {
            int receivedByte = 0;
            memset(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
            //receive data from the server
            receivedByte = recvfrom(m_ReceiveSocketId, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, (socklen_t*)&serverlen);
            if(receivedByte == -1)
            {

                Utility_SingleTon::printLog(LOG_ERROR,"[%s:%d#%s] UDP Client - receive error",__FILE__,__LINE__,__func__);
                close(m_ReceiveSocketId);
                pthread_exit(NULL);
                return false;
            }
            else if(receivedByte > 0)
            {
                string rMesg;
                rMesg.erase();
                for(int loop = 0; loop < receivedByte; loop++)
                    rMesg.append(1, buffer[loop]);
                Utility_SingleTon::printLog(LOG_DEBUG,"[%s:%d#%s] received message=%d",__FILE__,__LINE__,__func__, rMesg.length());
                QOMManager_SingleTon::getInstance()->setReceivedMessage(rMesg);
                raise(SIGUSR1);
            }

        }

        close(m_ReceiveSocketId);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return true;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks Yuvi.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `serverAddr.sin_addr` before the call to `bind`? Also, you never call `shutdown` anywhere?

Comment: `shutdown` is in destructor of the class. regarding bind I don't think so.. It's not working if i use `bind` after `serverAddr.sin_addr `

Comment: If the call to `shutdown` is in the destructor, haven't you already closed the socket in most cases by then?

Comment: `receiveMessage` is a thread function, and if I not call `shutdown` then execution stucks in `recvfrom` or in listening mode.So to get out from listening mode of socket, I have used `shutdown`. And execution continues after `recvfrom`..

Comment: I haven't used UDP socket much myself, but a quick Google search indicates that `shutdown` should not be used on UDP sockets. `recvfrom` blocks because the socket is blocking, either make the socket non-blocking or use the flag `MSG_DONTWAIT` to `recvfrom`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to call shutdown() for a UDP socket. From the man page:

```
The shutdown() call causes all or part of a full-duplex connection on the socket
associated with sockfd to be shut down.
```

If you call shutdown() on a UDP socket, it will return ENOTCONN
(The specified socket is not connected) because UDP is a connectionless protocol.

All you need to do is close the socket and set the socket to INVALID_SOCKET. Then in your destructor check whether the socket has already been set to INVALID_SOCKET before closing it.

Comment: IF I do so, then execution of thread stucks at `recvfrom` and thread never exits.

Comment: @Yuvi: if you close the socket, recvfrom() should return with ENOTSOCK. Is this not happening?

Comment: Yes, but how to get rid out of `recvfrom` blocking socket, DO you have any refernce link for that.

Comment: I think you need to post a bit more code. Are you trying to exit from recvfrom() by doing something in a different thread? If not then you might want to make your socket nonblocking and/or use select() to check for data being available on your socket. details on select() and other tcp details here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select